# RxSwift how to refresh BehaviourSubject better way?

Tags: swift, system.reactive, rx-swift, behaviorsubject

I have BehaviourSubject and I want to refresh items with last emitted value. I can do it example below,

```
 func refreshCurrent() {
    do {
        let items = try currentMatchList.value()
        if !(items.first?.items ?? []).isEmpty {
            refreshItems(sportId: try currentSport.value())
        }
    } catch {
        LOG.error(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
}
```

But I was wondering is there any built in RxSwift functionality I might use for same task?

I've found there was a `Variable()` type once upon a time but now it's gone and it's recommended to use BehaviourSubject it seems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching all the issues in the official github repo I've found long discussion about same problem [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1182) and it's closed.

**BUT** good news is as freak4pc states we can use RxCocoa class `BehaviourRelay` and it has a direct value access method

```
example("BehaviorRelay") {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let subject = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")

    print(subject.value)

    subject.addObserver("1").disposed(by: disposeBag)
    subject.accept("")
    subject.accept("")

    print(subject.value)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I get you correctly, but it seems like you want to store your value within a `BehaviourSubject`.

```
let foo = BehaviourSubject<[Something]>(value: [])
print(foo.value) //Empty Array
foo.accept([Something(), Something()])
print(foo.value) //Array of two somethings
```

Comment: yes but the problem is BehaviourSubject throws value which is sometimes hard to handle. 
here official doc 
    ```/// Gets the current value or throws an error.
    ///
    /// - returns: Latest value.
    public func value() throws -> Element {```

Comment: But you're using BehaviourSubject which throws value could you check latest documentation of RxSwift here https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Rx.playground/Pages/Working_with_Subjects.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift

Comment: Sorry. Use BehaviourRelay!